# jQuery submit form in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, browser, submit

Hello i used jQuery to submit a form when the select option is clicked and it worked perfectly on Firefox but not in Chrome and Safari any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

```
$(".willaya-submit").click(function(){
    $("#willaya-form").submit();
    })
```

Comment: Not all browsers raise a click event on option select. Sorry, the only solution is to not use a click event. You should instead be listening for the select to change.

Comment: Use the select's change event instead, it works everywhere and why would you need to submit anything if nothing changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use the `select` `change` event:

```
$(".willaya-submit").change(function(){  //change event
    $("#willaya-form").submit();
})
```

That event fires cross browser.

Cheers

Comment: Great! Could you please mark my answer as accepted? (green checkmark)